# How to modify key values in an object?

Tags: javascript, json, loops, object

I have a first object:

```
var objectOne = { my_key_1 : value1, my_key_2 : value2 } ;
```

I want to copy that object in another one, but with different key names.

Key names should be written like this "myKey1", so I made this function:

```
function stringRenaming(oldStr)  {
        oldVStr = oldStr.split("_") ;
    var newStr = oldStrr[0] ;
    for(i = 1 ; i < oldStr.length ; i++ ) {
        newStr += oldStr[i].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()+oldStr[i].substring(1) ;
    }
    return newStr ;
}
```

This code below copies the first object in the second one perfectly:

```
var objectTwo = {} ;
for (var i in objectOne) {
    if((objectOne[i] !== '') && (objectOne[i] !== undefined) && (objectOne[i] !== null) && (objectOne[i].length !== 0)) {
        objectTwo[i] = objectOne[i] ;
    }
}
```

But then, I can't find the way to apply my renaming function to the second object's keys. I tried to replace the line `objectTwo[i] = objectOne[i];` by `objectTwo[i] = objectOne[i];` but it don't work.

I tried to add another loop after the first one to edit the key values, but same effect. Most of the time I have the good key names, but with undefined values.

I don't know what to try now, can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the underscore and the following character with the upper case character.

```js
var format = s => s.replace(/(_)(.)/g, (_, __, c) => c.toUpperCase()),
    objectOne = { my_key_1: 'value1', my_key_2: 'value2' },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(objectOne).map(([k, v]) => [format(k), v]));

console.log(result);
```

Without arrow functions and destructuring.

```js
var format = function (s) { return s.replace(/(_)(.)/g, function (_, __, c) { return c.toUpperCase(); }); },
    objectOne = { my_key_1: 'value1', my_key_2: 'value2' },
    result = Object.keys(objectOne).reduce(function (r, key) {
        r[format(key)] = objectOne[key];
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz ! I have a last issue with your snippet. In fact, I have to implement my code in a tag management system (Google Tag Manager) which doesn't seems to support some syntax like arrows and array destructuring related to ECMAScript 6 (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp).
So I tried to "translate" your code:

```var format = function(s) { s.replace(/(_)(.)/g, (_, __, s)) ; s.toUpperCase() ; return s ; }```

I don't know if it works yet, but I'm completely lost about your third line of code. I don't know how to write it in a more classical way... Could you help ?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz with the second method "format" doesn't seems to apply to "result" :(